# How do i use the OnTriggerExit function and check inside if my ship collided?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to check if my ship/s collided and not some other objects.
So this is the script that i attached to a GameObject and the GameObject have box collider and Rigidbody. The box collider: Is Trigger set to on. And he size is 500 600 500. The Rigidbody i didn't change anything and Use Gravity is on.

When running the game i have many cloned gameobjects each one Tagged as "Sphere" but in the script when i check the tag name the collider is "Untagged".

What i'm trying to do is to make sure the collided object is a cloned spaceship.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class InvisibleWalls : MonoBehaviour {

    public float smooth = 1f;
    private Vector3 targetAngles;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Sphere") 
        {
            targetAngles = other.transform.eulerAngles + 180f * Vector3.up;
            other.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp (other.transform.eulerAngles, targetAngles, smooth * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the part where i'm trying to check and make that a ship is collided:

```
if (other.tag == "Sphere")
```

But when using break point it does stop on this line when the pbject collided but the other.tag the tag is "Untagged".

Screenshot showing the object spaceship cloned that is tagged as "Sphere"

[image: Sphere Tag]

And this screenshot showing the gameobject with the box collider and the rigidbody

[image: Collider gameobject]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i can gather,

You CrashLandedShip objects do not have colliders, adding colliders should work.

Also note that for triggers to work, One of the objects (the terrain or the ship) has to be a non-trigger (2 triggers will not cause a collision or trigger event)

So try this : Add a sphere collider to your `CrashLandedShip_UpsideDown` prefab and make sure they are **not** set with IsTrigger

The rest of your code looks fine.

Comment: Ok this is working now  the other variable in the OnTriggerExit tagged as "Sphere". But then it's entering the IF making the two lines inside but the ships never turn back they keep moving forward until they gone.

Comment: Your question was about colliders, not the movement of objects, would you mind asking a new question on stackoverflow to avoid confusion for future viewers of this question?

Comment: Created new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912393/why-after-the-spaceships-collide-with-the-box-collider-they-are-not-turning-back