# How can make the ships to move in the direction they are facing after rotated them?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the script i have 20 space ships. I store each ship start position and then check if each ship moved and travlled 50 distance i rotate the ship. This part is working fine.

Now i want to make that if i rotate each ship by 180 degrees once the ship rotated move to this direction. The problem is that the ship keep moving to the original direction even after rotated.

In the top of the script:

```
private float distanceTravelled;
public bool updateOn = true;
private Vector3 lastPosition;

List<bool> hasRotated = new List<bool>();
List<float> distanceTraveled = new List<float>();
List<Vector3> lastPositions = new List<Vector3>();
```

In the Start function i'm adding the start positions of all the childs and also set each child to false:

```
private void Start()
    {
        UpdateSpheres ();
        spheres = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MySphere");
        for(int index = 0; index < spheres[0].transform.childCount;index++)
        {
            Transform child = spheres[0].transform.GetChild(index);
            lastPosition = new Vector3(child.transform.position.x,child.transform.position.y,child.transform.position.z);
            lastPositions.Add (lastPosition);
            hasRotated.Add(false);
            distanceTraveled.Add(0f);
        }
    }
```

In the Update function i create the ships that's the UpdateSpheres and then move and roate them with the MoveShips:

```
private void Update()
    {
        UpdateSpheres();
        MoveShips ();
    }
```

Then in the MoveShips i'm trying to change the moving direction of each spaceship once it was rotated:

This is the original MoveShips function code:

```
private void MoveShips()
    {
        for (int index = 0;index < spheres[0].transform.childCount;index++)
        {
            Transform oneChild = spheres[0].transform.GetChild(index);
            lastPositions[index] = oneChild.transform.position;
            oneChild.transform.position += Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
        }

        if (updateOn == true) {
            for(int index =0;index < spheres[0].transform.childCount;index++)
            {
                Transform child = spheres[0].transform.GetChild(index);

                distanceTraveled[index] += Vector3.Distance (child.transform.position, lastPositions [index]);
                if (distanceTraveled[index] >= 50 && !hasRotated[index])
                {
                    child.transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (0f, 180f, 0f));
                    hasRotated[index] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then i changed the MoveShips function and tried to use the line:

```
oneChild.transform.position -= oneChild.transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
```

Or

```
child.transform.position += child.transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
```

But in all cases the ships keep moving the original direction then never change the movement according to where they are facing after the rotation.

If i will rotate them by 1 degree by 20 degrees or by 180 i want them to move to the direction they are now facing after the rotation. Even if i change the rotation on the X axis Y axis or Z axis then move up down right left forward depending what axis i rotate on. But what i want to do now first is to rotate them 180 degrees so they will change direction after rotation and move to this direction. Now to move reverse but to the face direction.

So i'm trying to use the child transform forward instead the Vector3.forward but no success so far.

```
private void MoveShips()
    {
        for (int index = 0;index < spheres[0].transform.childCount;index++)
        {
            Transform oneChild = spheres[0].transform.GetChild(index);
            lastPositions[index] = oneChild.transform.position;
            //oneChild.transform.position += Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
            if (distanceTraveled [index] >= 50 && !hasRotated [index]) {
                oneChild.transform.position -= oneChild.transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
            } else 
            {
                oneChild.transform.position += Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
            }

        }

        if (updateOn == true) {
            for(int index =0;index < spheres[0].transform.childCount;index++)
            {
                Transform child = spheres[0].transform.GetChild(index);

                distanceTraveled[index] += Vector3.Distance (child.transform.position, lastPositions [index]);
                if (distanceTraveled[index] >= 50 && !hasRotated[index])
                {
                    child.transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (0f, 180f, 0f));
                    hasRotated[index] = true;
                    //child.transform.position += child.transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Update:

The TurnShip turn them smooth but they are keep moving to the original direction and not changing the direction after the turn.

At top of script added:

```
public float smooth = 1f;
private Vector3 targetAngles;
```

This is how my MoveShips looks like now:

```
private void MoveShips()
    {
        for (int index = 0;index < spheres[0].transform.childCount;index++)
        {
            Transform oneChild = spheres[0].transform.GetChild(index);
            lastPositions[index] = oneChild.transform.position;
            oneChild.transform.position += Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
        }

        if (updateOn == true) {
            for(int index =0;index < spheres[0].transform.childCount;index++)
            {
                Transform child = spheres[0].transform.GetChild(index);

                distanceTraveled[index] += Vector3.Distance (child.transform.position, lastPositions [index]);
                if (distanceTraveled[index] >= 50 && !hasRotated[index])
                {
                    targetAngles = child.transform.eulerAngles + 180f * Vector3.up;
                    StartCoroutine (TurnShip (child.transform, child.transform.eulerAngles, targetAngles, smooth));
                    hasRotated[index] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the TurnShip function:

```
IEnumerator TurnShip(Transform ship, Vector3 startAngle, Vector3 endAngle, float smooth)
    {
        float lerpSpeed = 0;

        while(lerpSpeed < 1)
        {
            ship.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(startAngle, endAngle, lerpSpeed);
            lerpSpeed += Time.deltaTime * smooth;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why after the spaceships collide with the box collider they are not turning back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912393/why-after-the-spaceships-collide-with-the-box-collider-they-are-not-turning-back)

Comment: @Absinthe if i have a problem to ask it here as comment or at my other question in the link ? I want to ask you about the solution in the link.

Comment: @Absinthe in the other question your solution is working now i see with the smooth turn. But the ships keep moving the original direction and not moving to where they facing after the turn.  And i used your turn solution with this question here.

Comment: @Absinthe what i want to do is not ocllide the walls invisible walls but to make that ships will travell some distance and after that distance they will turn to the other side and then move to the other side.

Comment: @Absinthe i updated my question here with your solution from the other question. Sorry for the mess.

Comment: @Absinthe And also how can i change the turn speed to be much slower ? In the TurnShip function. I want that the ships will turn much slowly.

Comment: To move in the direction they face change this oneChild.transform.position += Vector3.forward to this oneChild.transform.position += oneChild.transform.forward. To turn more slowly reduce the value of your smooth variable

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Translate?

```
// Example Forwards
child.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
// Example Backwards
child.transform.Translate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
// you could use: left, right, up, down, forward, back
```

Documentation : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html

Comment: Did this help you find your solution?